# PHP Mail not sending when header redirects after

Tags: php, email, redirect

I am running into an odd problem

I have a php function that is sending an email and then redirects to another page.

When I comment out the redirect, the email is sent and received just fine.
When I have the redirect active, it redirects me to the correct page, but the email appears not to be sent.

```
function()
{
$email='nobody@nowhere.com';
$msg='Some test text message';
$from='FROM: reviews@mysite.com';

mail($email,'Feedback from your service',$msg,$from);

header('Location: review.php');
}
```

Comment: I don't see any way that could be. A statement can't affect something that happens before it.

Comment: How are you using the function? Plus you haven't named the function, so it's just sitting there.

Comment: Please show your actual code, I'm sure something is being lost in the copying, and not just the function name.

Comment: +3 for a php mail question? Something's fishy.

Comment: I thought so too @MikeB

Comment: Something you do not show us causes the error, like Barmar said, the reported behaviour is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The mail function returns true or false based on the email sending result, you should check this (maybe append it to the target URL for debugging):
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Do you have any body content when using the redirect? Maybe a simple "Redirecting..." message will solve the problem.

Comment: You got the problem the wrong way: "When I comment out the redirect, the email is sent and received just fine. When I have the redirect active, it redirects me to the correct page, but the email appears not to be sent."

Answer (score 0):

try to use as below:

```
function your_function()
{
    $email='nobody@nowhere.com';
    $msg='Some test text message';
    $from='FROM: reviews@mysite.com';

    if(mail($email,'Feedback from your service',$msg,$from)){

     header('Location: review.php');
    }
    else{
        // do falure loginc
     }

}
```

Comment: Can't have a space in `your function` for one thing, and how is OP going to access the function?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry it was my typo, modified

Comment: You got the problem the wrong way, OP sais, the header works, but the mail is not sent. Nothing to do with output. Also if the mail returned error, the header would not have worked

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ob_start(); at first line and ob_flush(); at the last line of your code. then you will be able to send headers with using header(); function.

Comment: You got the problem the wrong way, OP sais, the header works, but the mail is not sent. Nothing to do with output

Comment: you have to set headers for it $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";$header .= 'FROM: reviews@mysite.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); then mail('nobody@nowhere.com' , 'Feedback from your service', $msg, $header)

Answer (score 0):

```
function()
{
$email='nobody@nowhere.com';
$msg='Some test text message';
$from='FROM: reviews@mysite.com';

mail($email,'Feedback from your service',$msg,$from);

echo"<script language='javascript'>alert('mail Sent Successfully');

 window.location='review.php';
  </script>";
}
```